# проблема с apple sign in

Tags: javascript, angular, apple

я использваю на фpoнте Angular сперва у меня была ошибка clinet_id а теперь redirect_uri но URI совпадают на фpoнте и в конфигурации apple, можете показать как вы задали конфигурации v apple

```
AppleID.auth.init({
    clientId : 'clientId',
    scope : 'name',
    redirectURI : 'https://test.com/auth/login',
    state: 'what ever string to be remembered',
    usePopup : true
});
```

[image: ошибка apple]